# Referencing a website using Harvard style

Tags: style, citations

How can I reference a website using the Harvard style?

How would this be different if no author was listed?

Comment: I have no idea what the Harvard style is and how can a website have no authors? Machine-generated content?

Comment: Many a school requires such referencing. This was answered in the same resource I pointed to in a previous thread. I don't know (yet) how to point this to the other question...

Comment: It is on topic here. I've the answer. I'll just post it :)

Answer (score 7):

I have your answer **[at this site](http://www.usq.edu.au/library/help/referencing/harvard.htm)**.

For **Web document, no author** (there is an example provided on the site):

> Title Year, version number (if
>   applicable), description of document
>   (if applicable), name and place of the
>   sponsor of the source, viewed (Day
>   Month Year), URL (with either full location
>   details or just the main site details).

For **Web document, with author**:

> Author (the person or organisation
>   responsible for the site) Year (that
>   the site was created or last revised),
>   name and place of the sponsor of the
>   source, viewed (Day Month Year), URL.

and an example:

> The Body Shop Australia 2003, The Body
>   Shop Australia, Mulgrave, Victoria,
>   viewed 31 January 2003,
>   http://www.thebodyshop.com.au/.